# Responsive div blocks

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have 6 blocks in a row like that:

[image: blocks in a row]

In mobile and desktop version everything works as I want, but when I change `flex-direction` from `row` to `column`:

[image: 2 block in each row in mobile version]

In the desktop version, everything works well, but on the mobile version, blocks do not arrange 2 in each row, they are in a column. How can I solve that?

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.picture-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
}

.ring {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}


.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .ring {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - (40px / 3))
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1240px) {
  .ring {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 6) - (100px / 6))
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: With your current code I would have expected that on mobile it will be 2 rings for each column, not row. Isn't that the case as of now?

Comment: What resolution/browser are you using for the phone screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the desktop media query to keep the `column` layout and use the `flex-direction : row` for mobile and tablet ?

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .ring {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - (40px / 3))
  }

  .picture-box {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hxry2j1/)

Comment: can you help me in one more question?

Comment: please see this question. nobody can help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886219/can-not-visit-link-when-click-on-the-picture/54886464#54886464

Comment: so could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please use, https://getbootstrap.com/ framework .
and use html structure like this,

```
      <div class="picture-box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="ring">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, when a question is asked, please try to answer the question as opposed to suggesting a whole new way of doing something, unless it's relevant. In this case you're suggesting a whole new framework which the OP is not using. These types of suggestions should be comments, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please you can try this....

```
<style>
body{padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
img{width: auto;max-width: 100%;}
.picture-box{display: flex;flex-direction: row;justify-content:space-around; padding: 3rem 1.5rem;}
.ring{padding: 20px;margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;border: 1px solid green;text-align: center;}
.thumb{display: block;padding: 10px;border: 1px solid blue;}
@media(max-width: 1024px){.picture-box{flex-wrap: wrap;}.ring{width: calc(33.3% - 20px);}}
@media(max-width: 768px){.ring{width: calc(50% - 20px);}}
@media(max-width: 480px){.ring{width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;}}
</style>
```