# Can not visit link when click on the picture

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a 2 blocks. Photo and Video. In computer version when I click for them I can visit each link, but in mobile version they do no work, I mean they are not clickable. What is the problem?

```css
    .media-links {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .media-links a {
        display: block;
        /*height: 190px*/
        ;
        width: 40%;
        float: left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .media-links .video-link {
        background-image: url('../img/videos.png');
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    .media-links .foto-link {
        background-image: url('../img/photos.png');
    }
    .media-links a {
        height: 200px;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .media-links a {
            height: 260px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            width: 45%;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="media-links">
    <p><a class="video-link" href="/qalereya/video">Video</a> 
    <a class="foto-link" href="/qalereya/foto-qalereya">foto</a></p>
    </div>
```

I thought maybe it is due to blocks overlay each other. How can I solve that?

Comment: Try to add `display: inline-block;` in `video-link` and `foto-link`, both classes

Comment: @SatishSaini I did as you said if I understood you correctly. it did not help.

Comment: Do you have a link to the webpage where we can see it not working? Code snippet you shared seems to be working fine in mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

4 months ago I lived a problem similar this. When I click a link, I can visit each link, but **just apple devices on safari** not work. I changed my html link structure and I fixed. Sometimes some device/browser needs `touchend` event.

If you are living a problem just a device/browser. Maybe this link can help you: 
[iPad/iPhone hover problem causes the user to double click a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038898/ipad-iphone-hover-problem-causes-the-user-to-double-click-a-link)

Comment: the problem is that they do not clickable in each device, not only in IPad/IPhone